# Don't receive a response from api youtube - javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Tengo 3 archivos : 
- index.html
- style.css
- app.js

Cuando ejecuto el html no me devuelve la conexión del API de youtube, ya le indique el API KEY y demás.

```js
function tplawesome(e,t){res=e;for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){res=res.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g,function(e,r){return t[n][r]})}return res}

$(function() {
    $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       // prepare the request
       var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: "snippet",
            type: "video",
            q: encodeURIComponent($("#search").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+"),
            maxResults: 3,
            order: "viewCount",
            publishedAfter: "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"
       }); 
       // execute the request
       request.execute(function(response) {
          var results = response.result;
          $("#results").html("");
          $.each(results.items, function(index, item) {
            $.get("tpl/item.html", function(data) {
                $("#results").append(tplawesome(data, [{"title":item.snippet.title, "videoid":item.id.videoId}]));
            });
          });
          resetVideoHeight();
       });
    });
    
    $(window).on("resize", resetVideoHeight);
});

function resetVideoHeight() {
    $(".video").css("height", $("#results").width() * 9/16);
}

function init() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("AIzaSyC0Tf6tHJAHAXAyIvA2rGOJc-_Xo0Dln-0");
    gapi.client.load("youtube", "v3", function() {
        // yt api is ready
    });
}
```

```css
body { background: #f5c9c5; }
header { margin-top: 30px; }
header a { color: black; text-decoration: none; }
header a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
form { margin-top: 20px; }
form, #results { padding: 0 20px; }
.item { margin-bottom: 25px; }
.w100 { width: 100%; }

.btn-primary { background: #952b2b; border-color: #957575; }
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary:focus { background: #782b2b;  border-color: #952b2b; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>  
        <title>Your awesome Youtube search engine</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />     
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Awesome videos!" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>  
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1 class="w100 text-center"><a href="index.html">YouTube Viral Search</a></h1>
        </header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <form action="#">
                    <p><input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type something..." autocomplete="off" class="form-control" /></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Search" class="form-control btn btn-primary w100"></p>
                </form>
                <div id="results"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- scripts -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

ME devuelve el siguiente error :

cb=gapi.loaded_0:119 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').

y en la línea de código :   var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({

Agradecería su apoyo.

Saludos
Luis Sánchez